# View muito mais lenta que consulta direta mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, view

Estou migrando um sistema Delphi/Firebird para Php/MySql,

E me deparei com uma situação que não consigo entender,

Criei uma view no mysql para gerar um relatorio, a mesma view que tenho no firebird, porem quando executo a view trava e nao gera nada,

Acredito que não seja caso de otimização, pois copiando a query que originou a view e executando-a tudo funciona normalmente,

O que seria isso? alguma configuração? bug do mysql?

Não consigo entender o que há de errado,

Um detalhe importante que preciso mencionar é que hoje eu criei o mesmo banco no Postgres e funcionou perfeitamente, inclusive visivelmente mais rapido que o Firebird,

Segue abaixo o Script de Criacao de uma das Views,

````
```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS SEL_CUSTOS_APROPRIADOS;
CREATE VIEW SEL_CUSTOS_APROPRIADOS(
    LANCAMENTO,
    EMPRESA,
    EMPRESA_RAZAO,
    EMPRESA_CNPJ,
    ENTIDADE,
    ENTIDADE_RAZAO,
    ENTIDADE_CNPJ,
    ENTIDADE_CPF,
    EMPREENDIMENTO,
    EMPREENDIMENTO_DESCR,
    DATAAQUISICAO,
    QUADRA,
    LOTE,
    DESMEMBRAMENTO,
    EMISSAO,
    PARCELA_ID,
    PARCELA,
    VENCIMENTO,
    PARCELA_VALOR,
    COMPETENCIA,
    MES,
    CUSTO,
    CUSTOAPROPRIADO,
    INFRAMES,
    INFRAMES2,
    DATADISTRATO,
    CONTACTBEMPREENDCUSTO,
    CONTACTBRECEITADIFER,
    CONTACTBRECEITADIFERLP,
    CONTACTBDESPESADIFER,
    CONTACTBDESPESADIFERLP,
    EMPRESACONTABIL,
    CONTACTBDISTRATODRE,
    CONTACTBINFRAESTRUTURA)
AS
SELECT V.LANCAMENTO
       ,V.EMPRESA
       ,V.EMPRESA_RAZAO
       ,V.EMPRESA_CNPJ
       ,V.ENTIDADE
       ,V.ENTIDADE_RAZAO
       ,V.ENTIDADE_CNPJ
       ,V.ENTIDADE_CPF
       ,V.EMPREENDIMENTO
       ,V.EMPREENDIMENTO_DESCR
       ,V.DATAAQUISICAO
       ,V.QUADRA
       ,V.LOTE
       ,V.DESMEMBRAMENTO
       ,V.EMISSAO
       ,V.PARCELA_ID
       ,V.PARCELA
       ,V.VENCIMENTO
       ,V.PARCELA_VALOR
       ,V.COMPETENCIA
       ,V.MES
       ,V.CUSTO  VLR_CUSTO
       ,((V.CUSTO  + CUSTOINFRAACUMULADO) * V.PERCRECEBMES) + ((V.CUSTOINFRA)*(V.PERCRECEBACUMUL-V.PERCRECEBMES))  VLR_CUSTO_APROPRIADO
       ,COALESCE((SELECT SUM(VALOR) FROM SEL_INFRAESTRUTURA_MES  WHERE EMPRESA = V.EMPRESA AND EMPREENDIMENTO = V.EMPREENDIMENTO AND MES = V.MES AND MEScast(CONCAT(extract(year from v.ultrecebto),'-',extract(month from v.ultrecebto),'-01') as date)

  ORDER BY 21 ASC
```
````

Comment: Poderia fornecer códigos?

Comment: Oi boa tarde amigo, posso sim, 
editei a pergunta o colei o script de uma das Views la,
Obrigado.

Comment: As suas keys estão corretas? parece sim um caso de otimização..

Comment: É dificil afirmar com certeza, entretanto revisei umas 100x essas ligações, verifiquei também os índices das tabelas, aparentemente esta tudo certo, ate porque como eu disse, no firebird e postgres funciona normalmente, no mysql nao, o detalhe é que se eu copiar o select da view e executar uma query manual com ele
"SELECT V.LANCAMENTO,V.EMPRESA...
tudo funciona perfeitamente, somente quando eu executo o "SELECT * FROM VIEW" é que ocorre o travamento... por isso imagino que os selects estão corretos, e que deve ser algum erro do mysql

Comment: O "select" é executado sem "where" , e a view ? O "select" é executado com o "union" ? Se o "where" for aplicado em cada 'perna' do union um [indice pode ser aplicado na view não sei se o otimizador do mysql resolve , tive um problema assim em Oracle que resolvi por "hint" mas não achei agora o programa.

Comment: MySQL é um misterio meu amigo, como nao aparecia solucao, fiz uma gambiarra, resolvi armazenando os dados em outra tabela, 
Pra popular ela criei uma precedure que faz um loop(select for) dando um post dos dados, ai faço a requisicao dessa procedure pra gerar o relatorio pra gerar o relatorio.

Comment: É apresentado algum erro? Não custa perguntar, mas você aumentou o tempo limite de consulta no workbench (se estiver usando ele)?
Porque as vezes o MySql está com a configuração de tempo limite pra execução de um script. Caso seja maior, ele não trás o resultado e fica com um erro parecido com timeout.

Answer (score -2):

Está um pouco estranha a query, mas, eu tentaria fazer um join (left ou inner, depende da sua necessidade) em vez de usar tudo no where.
Uma coisa que reparei também é que você tem 2 campos que são subselects com sum com o mesmo nome (INFRAMES).
Talvez em vez de copiar e colar de um lugar do outro, a necessidade seja reescrever essa view ai.
Importante também, verificar se há o mesmo índice para ambas as tabelas para o join, da mesma forma que existia no FB (pelo seu comentário, entendi que funcionava normalmente no FB).
No mais, se você for resolver reescrever a query, comece com 1 tabela apenas, depois inclua a outra (e use JOINs). No final, inclua o Union. Ai você poderá 'debugar' onde está demorando mais.

Answer (score -3):

E fazendo só os dois selects fica lento também? Eu tentaria tentando executar apenas o select, e comentaria a linha do INFRAMES. Em outros bancos, subconsultas às vezes são mais rápidas do que joins. Começaria por aí.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).